# R svytable - Weighted prevalence ratios AND confidence intervals within strata of a covariate?

Tags: r, survey

I'm working on an analysis with weighted survey data in R and I'm trying to calculate survey weighted prevalence ratios for several different covariates. Using the code below, I can use svytable to calculate weighted prevalence of `condom_use` in the strata of each covariate (`age`, `rurality`, and `sexual_orientation`) comparing two time periods:

```
library(survey)
set.seed(123)

#Example dataset
dat <- data.frame(
  year = factor(sample(c("2019", "2020"), 100, replace = TRUE)),
  sv_weight = sample(1:150, 100, replace = TRUE),
  strat = sample(531011:532149, 100, replace = TRUE),
  condom_use = sample(c(0, 1), 100, replace = TRUE),
  age = factor(sample(c("18-29", "30-39", "40-49"), 100, replace = TRUE)),
  rurality = factor(sample(c("Rural", "Urban"), 100, replace = TRUE)),
  sexual_orientation =  factor(sample(c("Straight", "Not straight"), 100, replace = TRUE)))

#Survey design options
options(survey.lonely.psu = "adjust")
design <- svydesign(data = dat,
                    id = ~1,
                    strata = ~strat,
                    weights = ~sv_weight)

#Creating prevalence tables for each covariate
table2 <- svytable(~year + condom_use + age, design) %>% prop.table(margin = 1)
table2

table3 <- svytable(~year + condom_use + rurality, design) %>% prop.table(margin = 1)
table3

table4 <- svytable(~year + condom_use + sexual_orientation, design) %>% prop.table(margin = 1)
table4
```

From these tables, I can calculate a prevalence ratio by dividing the prevalence of condom use in 2020 to the prevalence in 2019. I'm looking for the prevalence ratio within each strata, like for example comparing condom use in "rural" in 2020 compared to in "rural" in 2019.

My problem is that this method doesn't give me the option of calculating a confidence interval. Does anyone know of a method for getting a weighted prevalence ratio AND 95% confidence interval within each strata of a covariate?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generalised linear model for a prevalence ratio.

Here, the coefficient marked `year2020` is the log prevalence ratio in the 'Not straight`group and the interaction coefficient is the log prevalence ratio in the`Straight` group

```
> summary(model<-svyglm(condom_use~sexual_orientation*year, design=design, family=quasibinomial(log)),df=Inf)

Call:
svyglm(formula = condom_use ~ sexual_orientation * year, design = design, 
    family = quasibinomial(log))

Survey design:
svydesign(data = dat, id = ~1, strata = ~strat, weights = ~sv_weight)

Coefficients:
                                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)                          -0.7267     0.2506  -2.900  0.00373 **
sexual_orientationStraight            0.2618     0.2931   0.893  0.37175   
year2020                              0.1059     0.3469   0.305  0.76018   
sexual_orientationStraight:year2020  -0.2215     0.4348  -0.509  0.61046
```

Now exponentiate the coefficients to get prevalence ratios

```
> exp(coef(model))
                        (Intercept)          sexual_orientationStraight 
                          0.4834875                           1.2992183 
                           year2020 sexual_orientationStraight:year2020 
                          1.1116982                           0.8013263
```

The `1.111696` matches what I get from your `table4` for the ratio in `Not straight`.

Now for confidence intervals use `confint`

```
> exp(confint(model,ddf=Inf))
                                        2.5 %    97.5 %
(Intercept)                         0.2958642 0.7900927
sexual_orientationStraight          0.7315182 2.3074863
year2020                            0.5632601 2.1941424
sexual_orientationStraight:year2020 0.3417622 1.8788616
```

You can also subset the data and fit the model just to each stratum at a time.

Note: the `ddf=Inf` is because your design has only 3 design degrees of freedom, which isn't enough to actually estimate a confidence interval. If your real data has more degrees of freedom you can omit it.